# cellForRowAtIndexPath for TableView not being called?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to build a simple TableView in Swift, but instead of conforming to the datasource protocol within my ViewController, I wanted to create a new class that will serve as the DataSource. Unfortunately, with this approach, I'm not able to get anything to load in my ViewController.

This is my ViewController Class:

```
class SaladViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var saladTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let tableData = LunchTableData()
        self.saladTable.dataSource = tableData
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

And this is my DataSource class:

```
class LunchTableData: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    var things = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return things.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")

        let itemText = cell!.viewWithTag(100) as! UILabel
        itemText.text = things[indexPath.row]

        return cell!
    }
}
```

RowAtIndexPath is getting called fine, so I'm just not sure why CellForRowAtIndexPath isn't ever being called. I've set a breakpoint and it never hits it.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think tableData is destroyed after viewDidLoad() is finished.

So move the following line just below the @IBOutlet weak var saladTable: UITableView! line.

```
let tableData = LunchTableData()
```

Hope this help you

So full code

```
class SaladViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var saladTable: UITableView!

    let tableData = LunchTableData()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.saladTable.dataSource = tableData
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what needs to be done. The table data was declared as a local variable, which means that it gets destroyed when its scope comes to an end, which, in your case, is when `viewDidLoad()` is finished.

Comment: Yes, the data source property is `weak`.

Comment: That was it! Thank you! Forgot about variable scopes... Also, what does "weak" vs. "strong" mean in Swift?

Comment: Good question

So variables declared weak doesn't increase reference count of original object and become nil when original object is destroyed.

Instead strong will increase reference count when assigned. 
When you do not specify any thing before "var", it is strong by default.
For more information please check "Automatic Reference Counting"  of Swift Programming Language Guide.